# How do I select an element within a variable to trigger play <video>

Tags: javascript, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm using the RoyalSlider plugin. I'm getting the DOM content of the current slide using the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sliderS = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider');
    sliderS.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(e, slideObject) {  
        var currentDOM = jQuery('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider').currSlide.content.context;
        // I want to PLAY the <video> in the currentDOM variable here.
    });
});
```

How does one go about selecting the < video > in the variable? I've tried everything from .getElementById() to .find(). Nothing is working. HALP!

To look at what I have going on: [Current Sample](http://dop.craftedbykota.com/)

Comment: and a "document.getElementsByTagName()" ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, what's wrong with simply using a `video` jQuery tag selector and supplying your DOM element as the context to search?

e.g.

```
var $video = $('video', currentDOM);
```

*As your website does not appear to have videos, yet, I can't check this.*